# Manually go to catch statement of do...catch

Tags: swift, do-catch

I want to test if an array's count is greater than 0, otherwise dismiss the current view.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
do {
    let pets = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    guard pets.count > 0 else {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    dateCreated = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(pets[0].dateCreated))
} catch {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm wondering if I can just manually send the `do..catch` into the `catch` if the  count is not greater than 0, that way I don't have to have `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` written twice. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you don't care about the `error` therefore you can use `try?` instead of `do-catch`:

```
guard
    let pets = try? self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request), 
    !pets.isEmpty
else {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    return 
}

dateCreated = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(pets[0].dateCreated))
```

Another option is to move the duplicated code into a function/closure, e.g.

```
let onError: () -> Void = {
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

do {
    let pets = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    guard pets.count > 0 else {
       onError()
       return
    }
    dateCreated = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(pets[0].dateCreated))
} catch {
    onError()
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine, but I figured he should see that throwing is an option.

Comment: @DanielT. I don't think that throwing a fake error is a good option in any scenario. You could for example remove the duplication by defining `let onError: () -> Void = { self.dismiss(...) }` and call `onError` from both branches(). That's still better than faking errors.

Comment: I agree, but there might be a larger context that the questioner or some future reader is dealing with where the error wouldn't be fake. Like I said though, your answer is better for the exact question asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wedded to the `do` block, you could do this:

```
struct MyError: Error { }

do {
    let pets = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    guard pets.count > 0 else {
        throw MyError()
    }
    dateCreated = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(pets[0].dateCreated))
} catch {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd like to try using a `defer`.

The `guard` condition isn't returning. That's problematic.

Try something like

```
defer {
    self.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)
}

do {
    let pets = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    guard pets.count > 0 else {
        return
    }
    dateCreated = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(pets[0].dateCreated))
} catch {
    // TODO - do any error work required if no pets.  Possibly nothing.
}
```

Using `defer` will guarantee that line of code gets called on exit of the method.

Comment: But the call to `dismiss` isn't wanted if the code runs successfully.

Comment: Missed that req.  Sorry. Yes, Sulthan has the right answer.